# Get next post in same category not working WP 4.7.4

Tags: categories, single, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have posts which assigned 1 of 2 different categories.

On the single post view i want to show a next and previous link of posts with the SAME category.

This should be straightforward, i've tried using get_previous_post etc but i cannot exclude posts assigned to the other category.

I've tried

`$prevPost = get_adjacent_post(TRUE,'129',TRUE);`

where 129 is the id of the category i want to exclude, but this does not work.

The posts are assigned categories correctly i.e. they are not assigned both categories.

The query is as follows

```
SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.menu_order < '2' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY p.menu_order DESC LIMIT 1
```

As you can see it doesn't reference the category to exclude.

Is this a wordpress bug or am i missing something here?

Thanks,

Sophie

Answer (score 1):

Use `the_post_navigation( $args );` to display next and previous links in your template for a single post. To restrict links to the same category, your `$args` array, in its simplest form, should be:

```
$args = array(
    'in_same_term' => true,
    );
```

Other parameters are optional. Get their list [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_navigation/#parameters).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it still pulls through a post with a different category. I'm setting 'in_same_term' to true in my previous example but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try to add `'taxonomy' => 'category',` to your `$args` array. I didn't do it because `'category'` is supposed to be a default.

Comment: No joy unfortunately. Still not working as expected. There's an issue with get_adjacent_post i think, it constructs $where based on the term you've excluded here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1647 , then it changes $where here so that it doesnt exclude that term https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1716

Comment: Do not use `$prevPost = get_adjacent_post(TRUE,'129',TRUE);` and use standard query. Display all posts. When you select a single post, your 'next' and 'previous' links should select posts within SAME category.